# How do I pass parameters into a stored procedure run in a pass through query in access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a few linked tables between Microsoft Access and SQL Server. I implemented Access to do all the work in the queries for the database but after further review it was just to slow so I decided to run all the queries in SQL Server by creating stored procedures and have Access just executing a stored procedure as a query. The problem is that some of these stored procedures require parameters. Therefore the code in Access looks like this:

```
Exec getConsumption @Value1 = Product1
```

@Value 1 is the parameter needed and Product1 is what I want to pass into the parameter

**This all seems to work but is there a way to prompt a user for a text box so that whatever they enter will be passed into the parameter rather than having to go hard code it in every time it needs to be changed ?**

Comment: you can't. You must construct the sql and eventually create a new query object.